# Sphinx with both Python and Matlab (sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain): Import fail

Tags: python, matlab, python-sphinx

I have a project including a Python package as well as some Matlab code, which should all go into the same documentation created by Sphinx.
The Python part of the documentation works flawlessly quite some time already - the Matlab part was added now and makes some trouble.

The data structure more or less is as follows:

```
|- python
     |- modules
     |- including subpackages
                            |- some sub-modules
|- matlab
      |- scripts
      |- functions
|- docs
      |- source
              |- conf.py
              |- matlab.rst
              |- python.rst
              |- index.rst
              |- ...
```

The most relevant lines in `conf.py` are prob. the following:

```
import os
import sys
# for the Python autodoc package
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.napoleon', 'sphinxcontrib.matlab', 'sphinx.ext.autodoc']
# Path to the Matlab files
matlab_src_dir = '../../matlab'
#matlab_src_dir = '<<abssolute_path>>/matlab'
```

As you see, I tried both relative and absolute paths for `matlab_src_dir`. So far, without any difference.

The `python.rst`, which was created automatically by `apidoc`, contains:

```
python package
==============

.. automodule:: python
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:

Subpackages
-----------

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   python.subpackages
```

The `matlab.rst` was created manually and contains:

```
matlab package
==============

.. mat:automodule:: matlab
   :members:
   :undoc-members:
   :show-inheritance:

Subscripts
----------

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 4

   matlab.function_file
```

Thus, `python.rst` and `matlab.rst` are more or less the same but with `mat:automodule` for Matlab according to the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain/).

Finally, `index.rst` contains:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   
   python

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   
   matlab
```

Now, when I run Sphinx' `make html` I receive the following error, which results in a nice Python documentation but an empty Matlab documentation:

```
WARNING: [sphinxcontrib-matlabdomain]: failed to import module 'matlab'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<<username>>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sphinxcontrib\mat_documenters.py", line 117, in import_object
    obj = self.module = modules[self.modname]
KeyError: 'matlab'
```

What am I missing here. Why can't Sphinx find the matlab folder with the containing m-files?

And if that should be solved, maybe a secondary question: is there any similar function as `apidoc` for Matlab files, so that I do not need to create all *.rst files myself?

Thank you for any hints!

BTW: I am running on Sphinx v4.4.0 under Python 3.9.7.

Comment: I don't know what you used for an absolute path, but that is what `matlab_src_dir` requires. IOW, perhaps something like `/home/username/projects/project_name/matlab` or maybe `/project_name/matlab`. Or look at the example in the project source code: https://github.com/sphinx-contrib/matlabdomain/blob/master/docs/conf.py#L43

Comment: This is exactly what I tried. Well, almost, I am on Windows here. Something like "D:/Projekte/.../matlab". Sorry, I can not give you the full path due to confidential informations ;)

Comment: Did you try the example in the source code at the link I provided? That would be more reliable.

Comment: Thank you very much, was was not able to test it until now. Your link gave me the right direction today. See the answer I have written. Again: thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither providing a hard-coded absolute path to `matlab_src_dir` nor providing `os.path.abspath(relative_path)` lead to success.

Thanks to Steve Piercy, who mentioned an example in the comments, I found that I should use `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(relative_path))`. As such, the errors are gone and Sphinx is working.
This is interesting, because I have already tried `os.path.abspath(relative_path to the parent of the package)` before, which I would expect is doing the same than `os.path.dirname()`. Anyway, I got a working solution now.

If anybody would have an idea about the second question ("is there any similar function as apidoc for Matlab files, so that I do not need to create all *.rst files myself?") I would be really happy.